# Can't Download PDF from HTTPS in IE 6,7,8

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, pdf, download

```
mpp.myPDF(Response.OutputStream);  // PdfDocument...
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
```

【HTTP】

IE、Firefox、Chrome ： All Okay

【HTTPS】

IE 9,10,11 ： Okay
Firefox ： Okay
Chrome ： Okay

***But*** in

**IE 6,7,8 = X...... it shows the Error**

> Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site, the
>   requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found.

```
protected void OnPrintClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if ((Request.Browser.Browser == "IE") && (Request.Browser.MajorVersion < 9))
    {
        Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now;
        Response.Expires = -1441;
        Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-store");
        Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Expires = 0;
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.HeaderEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
    }

   //↑
   // I try to add these code are invalid....【Https】 IE 6、7、8.... X

    mpp.myPDF(Response.OutputStream);  // PdfDocument...
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
 }
```

How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider setting the `ContentType` to `"application/pdf"` and clearing everything before attempting to stream to the client/browser:

```
    Response.Buffer = false;

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename");         
    mpp.myPDF(Response.OutputStream);  // PdfDocument...
    //could also consider: 
    //Response.TransmitFile("path to document");
    //Response.BinaryWrite((byte[]) stream);
    Response.End()
```

Comment: ty~ ^^ !!  Thank you for your guidance, the problem I tried the whole day. Thank you very much